# passing strings into sprintf syntax

Tags: php

I am just trying to pass a date into sql as a DATE (XXXX-XX-XX format), but I can't seem to get sprintf to accept my string date-components.  I seem to be following the documentation correctly. using php5.5

```
$year = ($_POST['year']);
$month = ($_POST['month']); 
$day = ($_POST['day']);
```

var_dump shows:

```
 string(4) "1991" string(1) "8" string(1) "5"
```

however both of these var_dumps are empty:

```
$dobexpanded =sprintf("%04s-%02s-%02s", $year, $month, $day);
$dateofbirth = (STR_TO_DATE('$dobexpanded', '%Y-%m-%d'));
var_dump($dobexpanded);
var_dump($dateofbirth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$dobexpanded =sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day);
$dateofbirth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dobexpanded));
var_dump($dobexpanded);
var_dump($dateofbirth);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Kept it as strings, but the date format converted.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
```

Comment: thanks. I ended up using the answer above but I am confident this would have worked as well.